# Dose WSO2 Data Services Server support DB Sharding and Read/Write Splitting?

Tags: database, wso2, sharding, split, wso2-data-services-server

With the popularity of Internet applications, mass data storage and access has become a bottleneck in the DB design.

Dose WSO2 Data Services Server support DB Sharding(including Vertical Sharding and  Horizon Sharding) and Read/Write Splitting?

Answer (score 0):

Splitting database is a DB design task.I don't think it is a job of data service server.(im not sure about this)
As far as i know, dataservice server supports [distributed transaction](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS310/Distributed+Transactions+Sample), which can be used when querying/updating multiple  databases..